# Can I get google to ban a spamming site from Adsense ?

Tags: google, google-adsense, spam

I've noticed a "site" that stole some of my content and they are displaying google ads. Not responding to my email. I'm quite certain that most of their content is stolen, either from other sites or from newsgroups. Whom should I contact at google so that they would hopefully deprive that site of their only source of income?

Comment: What a pitty,because of Google Adsense income,internet has started to be a rabbit.Most of blog sites have stolen articles and this is only to provide google adsense income. There is not anything to prevent this. My web sites' contents also have been stolen many other web sites.But Google knows which is the original conent and which is copy for the Google rank of these kind of web sites but it takes time.

Comment: on the contrary. Many people are now trying to bring high quality content to the web. Same incentive: traffic and the outlook of money!

Comment: @Lo-lsauer I think many people still do the bare minimum to rank for certain keywords.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used Google to find [this](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?ctx=hc_footer&answer=18386&hl=en_US&gsessionid=TxP_XBDCXM9paMt5xeF-ug) (emphasis mine):

> If you've found a site violating the AdSense program policies, please
> let us know. The information you provide will be forwarded to a
> specialist for further review.
>
> Some issues require specific information for an investigation to be
> completed. Those issues include:
>
> - **[Copyrighted content](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?answer=146178): Distribution of my copyrighted content without my
>   permission**
> - Unauthorized ad code on my site: Ad code was placed on my
>   site without my permission.
> - Ad complaints: Send feedback about a
>   specific Google ad displayed on a website.
>
> If the violation you've noticed is related to AdSense, but doesn't fall into one of these
> categories, then please use our [violation report form](http://adsense.google.com/support/bin/request.py?contact=violation_report). Alternatively,
> you can report a site through the "Ads by Google" or "AdChoices" logo
> which is displayed on each ad unit. Simply click "Ads by Google" or
> "AdChoices" on the site you'd like to report, and then submit your
> feedback on the resulting page.